# AngularJS - trigger ngChange?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some custom directive and I've bound ng-model and ng-change directives info this.

Example:

```
<custom-directive ng-model="users" ng-change="changed()">

</custom-directive>
```

directive after execute contains some inputs, textareas etc. I want to execute function bound into `ng-change`, `changed()` always when something is changed in this inputs, textareas.

Can I execute `ng-change` from directive `controller` or `link`?

Like this for example:

```
.directive('customDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        require: 'ngModel',
        templateUrl: 'src/template.html',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
            executeNgChange();
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: I think you can do a `$scope.$eval(attrs.ngChange)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to bind the function in `ng-change` in your directive using angular's **Scope Function Expression Binding**:

```
.directive('customDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            change: '&ngChange'
        }
        templateUrl: 'src/template.html',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
            scope.change();  // or use ng-change="change()" in your directive template 
        }
    };
})
```

I haven't tested this myself but hopefully it helps you.